# Filtering The Analyzer report in Pentaho

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-design-studio

[image]I successfully created the Pentaho  Analyzer report of some data . Than i apply filter on one column let suppose `house_id`  and which contains the data `H1,H10,H15,H20` and in filter option when i type `H1`  it gives output `H1,H10,H15` because filter has option `contains` .
Is there any method from which I Only Get The `H1` result ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the filter option, comparison box, click it, it will show you other options, select "=" and it will give you exact match...

Comment: there is no option of comparison box plz help

Comment: What step you are using

Comment: after i getting the data i drag the column on which i want to filter than it has only inculed or exclud or contain and not contain option and nothing else

Comment: Use the same filter step

Comment: but there is no option of equal please see the picture

Comment: Why you are using design studio? Why not pentaho data integration?

Comment: it is the project requirement is it possible here in design studio ?

Comment: Select from a list includes is the same I think

Comment: I have not used it. I will install it in the morning in office